# what does clamp_ does in pytorch and how to change it to the tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, torch, clamp

```
   prior_boxes = torch.FloatTensor(prior_boxes).to(device)  # (8732, 4)
   prior_boxes.clamp_(0, 1)  # (8732, 4)
```

what dooes clamp_ do in pytorch and how to change it to the tensorflow 2.0?

I'm not sure what clamp_ do exactly?

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer it helps solve your question. Or let me know that the problem with my answer.

Comment: It is interesting, because you added the tag "clamp" and its description says "Constrains a value between a lower and upper bound". It should answer your last question. Perhaps you just need to know that the trailing "_" means that it happens in-place.

Answer (score 3):

`clamp_(0, 1)` Clamp all elements in `prior_boxes` into the range [ 0, 1].

Tensorflow:

`tf.clip_by_value`
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value